# How to run a query from SQL in RJDBC Oracle Database?

Tags: sql, r, oracle

I can achieve the connection to my oracle database. I have no problem to obtain a table from the base with the query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
```

but when i write:

`SELECT * , COLUMN1 FROM TABLE1`

it shows error:

> in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ", 
>   :    Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for select *; column1 FROM
>   Table1 (ORA-00911: carÃ¡cter no vÃ¡lido )

Any suggestions?

Comment: Assuming you already have COLUMN1 in your resultset, can you try like: select *,COLUMN1 as mynewcolumn from table1

Comment: no, i try this but it not be useful

Answer (score 2):

Use a table alias, e.g.

This doesn't work (as you already know it):

```
SQL> select *, dname from dept;
select *, dname from dept
        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

But this works OK:

```
SQL> select d.*, d.dname from dept d;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC           DNAME
---------- -------------- ------------- --------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK      ACCOUNTING
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS        RESEARCH
        30 SALES          CHICAGO       SALES
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON        OPERATIONS

SQL>
```